# Using Kerberos/ntlm2 auth for proxy plug-in path in chrome options while using selenium chrome driver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, kerberos, proxy-authentication, ntlmv2

I have already created a proxy plugin path for chrome driver options with classic manifestjson and background is string and calling callbackFn for authCreds now the proxy getting passed here is of basic/ntlm auth I want to now use the ntlm2 or Kerberos auth for the proxy creds and accessing the web-pages does anyone has any exp with this on how to get the ntlm2 or Kerberos auth while using the selenium chrome driver extension?

I tried the Kerberos auth via auth-negotiate-delegate-allowlist and auth-server-allowlist and passed allowed domain list didn’t helped